# I used support bitcoin wallet address by mistake! How do I get that back to put into my wallet

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet, bitcoind, address, funds

New to bitcoin and I use their support Bitcoin wallet address instead of using my wallet. How do I get those funds back?

Answer (score 2):

> **I use their support Bitcoin wallet address instead of using my wallet**

Tell *them* you sent *them* money by mistake, mention the transaction ID, and ask *them* to send you the same amount back (less transaction fees).

How you do this depends on who *they* are (and whether you know who *they* are).

Since there are no Bitcoin police and no-one in charge of Bitcoin, you will likely have to rely on the goodwill of *the recipient*.